# How to use javas built-in javascript engine to run script on a web-page?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I want to show lyrics for songs in my player. I used to use lyricsplugin.com because it had a lot of English and Russian lyrics, but recently they've changed their web-site from being a static page to an ajax-powered page. Searching lyrics follows this pattern:

http://www.lyricsplugin.com/winamp03/plugin/?artist=Linkin%20Park&title=Numb

It shows an empty page and this in body onload:

```
javascript:getContent('Linkin%20Park', 'Numb', '1281528101', '5e22e4e3979026a9af59ee16ff82fe1f')
```

while `getContent` looks like this:

```
function getContent(artist, title, time, check) { 
xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
if(xmlHttp == null)
{
    return;
}
var url = "content.php?artist=" + artist + "&title=" + title + "&time=" + time + "&check=" + check;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

`stateChanged()` then puts response into corresponding div in the page.

So I guess I can download the page and build a DOM tree since it is XHTML. How do I use the built in rhino engine to execute the javascript and preferably override the `stateChanged()` function? I don't seem to be able to call that `content.php` script directly.

No other resource has that many lyrics (especially Russian) except for lyrics.wikia.com, but they don't allow screen scraping.

**UPDATE:**

lyricsplugin seems to be using [justsomelyrics.com](http://justsomelyrics.com) and there is a google custom search box. How can I access it from java?

Comment: one might argue that "lyricsplugin.com" doesn't allow screen scraping either! ;-)

Comment: @scunliffe there are no Terms of Service or any kind of advertisements , so we can only assume ;)

Comment: Java has a built-in JavaScript engine?

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Yes, since java 1.6 it includes a slightly modified version of the rhino engine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is the [SWT Browser component](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html).  Simply call `setURL(String)` and it will display the web page.  This gives you a full fledged browser with Javascript and everything.